# Different Image processing results from Java and Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, javax.imageio

I was doing a simple image processing task which I prototyped on Matlab, then made a port to Java. After executing the task on Java, I noticed different results. Is this a platform specific issue?

The task I was doing so far involves obtaining an image's green channel, computing the percentage of a number of pixels with values of a certain range, and computing the arithmetic mean of that channel. Code and results are shown:

**Matlab**

```
   a = imread('large.jpg');
   g = a(:,:,2);
   [x,y] = size(b);
   count = 0;
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if g(i,j) < 90 & g(i,j) > 30
            count = count + 1;
            %Mistake part for arithmetic mean. Thanks to james_alvarez
            g(i,j) = 255;
        end
    end
end
 count
 (count/(3000*2400))*100
 mean2(g)

----------

1698469
23.5898
165.9823
```

**Java**

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Function.class.getResource("large.jpg"));
int gCount = 0;
int meanCount = 0;

int w = img.getWidth();

int h = img.getHeight();
for(int i = 0 ; i < w ; i++){

        for(int j = 0 ; j< h ; j++){

            Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(i,j));
            int g = c.getGreen();

            meanCount += g;

            if(g < 90 && g > 30)
                gCount++;
    }
}

System.out.println(gCount);
System.out.println((gCount/(3000.0*2400.0))*100.0);
System.out.println(meanCount/(3000*2400));

----------

1706642
23.70336111111111
121
```

Why do they give considerably different results?

Comment: Image size is 3000x2400

Comment: Made a tiny mistake when inserting the code here and cleaning it up for the question. It's corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Matlab code you also add the line:

```
g(i,j) = 255;
```

Which could be the possibility for why the mean 'g' is higher in the matlab version.  Otherwise are your indexes right for the counting?  e.g. in the matlab you use size(b), rather than getting the width/height directly from the image.

Comment: size(b) gets the size as intended

Comment: Indeed that g = 255 part caused a problem, because of the different implementations of the average means + I forgot to remove this part from the matlab from previous testing. However, what about the number of those pixels themselves?

Comment: The code is correct so, if the image sizes are correct then it may be due to the different JPEG decoding algorithms, i.e. different ways of rounding?  You could try saving the result of both algorithms as a bmp and comparing those bmps.

Comment: @AhmedFarid - james_alverez is correct.  The slight errors in between both the readings of the image pixels is due to the methods on how the JPEG decoding is performed.  I remember seeing a post here on StackOverflow (I wish I could find it...) where someone made the same observations between Java and MATLAB and we deduced that this was the reason.  The only possible way you could escape this is to use images that are **lossless** (PNG, TIF, etc.)